# Add horizontal and vertical lines to a Plot

Tags: plotting

I have this function:

```
f[x] := -29.9092 + 0.456839 x
```

Now I plot it:

```
Plot[f[x],{x,120,150}]
```

If I want to highlight a specfic point:

```
 x1 = {{130,f[130]}}
```

I would like to have a vertical line going from the x-Axis to that point and ending at that point (like: Filling -> Bottom) and a horizontal line going from the y-Axis and ending at that point.

How can I do it ?

Comment: `Epilog->Line[{{130,0},{130, f[130]}}]`

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished using `ListLinePlot` in combination with the original `Plot`:

```
f[x_] := -29.9092 + 0.456839 x

Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 120, 150}], 
 ListLinePlot[{{{120, f[130]}, {130, f[130]}}, {{130, f[120]}, {130, 
     f[130]}}}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

You can also can also get the same effect using @DavidGStork suggestion:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 120, 150}, 
 Epilog -> {Line[{{130, f[120]}, {130, f[130]}}], 
   Line[{{120, f[130]}, {130, f[130]}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great !! Thanks ! :)

Comment: `Line[{{130, f[120]}, {130, f[130]}, {120, f[130]}}]` should also work and is simpler.